# Where do I find Indicator Applets?

Tags: indicator, ayatana

Looking at a number of screenshots from various ubuntu articles namely the one below from OMG Ubuntu the user has applets for an array of programs such as Dropbox, Transmission, etc. Is a resource for such applets, or how do I obtain and enable applets like these?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Desktop Screenshot with Indicator Applets]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a resource for listing new applets, but I can tell you a little about the applets in your screenshot and some others that might be of interest?

- Volume : Should be present by default
- Dropbox: http://www.dropbox.com
- Banshee: Install via Ubuntu Software Center
- *(Not sure about the square one..? Anyone?)*

You may also be interested in the UbuntuOne sync applet:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/indicator-workspaces-updated-for-maverick/

The link above will also show you how to add third-party applets to the main menu on start-up.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Dropbox isn't in the Software Center, you have to download it from dropbox.com. (The indicator support is in a forum build actually)

Comment: Well spotted Jorge! Apologies!!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but that screenshot is (at most) a combination of Indicator Applet and the older Notification Area. You can tell because Indicator Applet doesn't have a move handle and their tray does.

It looks like the first two (Networking and DropBox) are Notification Area and the rest are Indicator applet.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.04 -and obviously 10.10- has all of them enabled by default. Except of Banshee and Dropbox.
For Banshee indicator, open Banshee, disable the tray icon, install [Banshee Appindicator](https://apt.ubuntu.com/p/banshee-extension-appindicator). For Drobox follow [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/05/dropbox-adds-indicator-applet.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can get ubuntu one indicator applet follow this instruction :

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/ubuntu-one-indicator-applet-gets-a-ppa/

as said tommed this is for workplace applet :

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/indicator-workspaces-updated-for-maverick/